# Bar Mounted to bottom of screen if listview overflows

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I want the bottom_control_bar to be mounted to the bottom of the listview, however if the listview overflows and has to be scrolled through I want it to be mounted to the bottom of the screen so that it is always visible.  Currently if the listView doesnt fill the whole page, everything is fine, however if it overflows the bottom_control_bar isn't visible at all.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/grey05"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.albert.betterapp.MyBets">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_control_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#C9C193"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView91"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:text="Accumulator(5)"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView101"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:text="Token:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView121"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/wingreen"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_control_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout23"
    android:background="#C9C193"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="@string/stake"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:text="500"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:text="@string/potentialwinnings"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/wingreen"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:text="6000"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />



</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout23"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/top_control_bar"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Main ListView
         Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
    -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/betslistview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/betcolor"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add `android:layout_above = @+id/bottom_control_bar` to your `linearLayout23`

Answer (score 1):

The best option here is to add a footer to the `ListView` when all the elements don't exceed the screen height. If the sum of all the `ListView` item's height is greater than the screen height you switch the layout type for one where you have a `ViewGroup` (`Relative Layout`) with a `ListView` (without the footer) on the top and a `LinearLayout` at the bottom (the desired footer).

**EDIT:**    
- Create a isolated layout with your **bottom_control_bar**;
- Create a layout with a `ListView` and a `LinearLayout` bellow where you `include` (in your XML) that **bottom_control_bar**;
- In your `Activity` `onCreate` you should implement the logic I've explained above and if:
    
    A - your list height doesn't exceeds the screen you should set your **bottom_control_bar** visibility to `GONE` and add that **bottom_control_bar** as a header to your `ListView`.
    
    B - your list height exceeds the screen you don't add a header to your `ListView` and don't change the **bottom_control_bar** visibility to `GONE`, in other words, you do nothing to your layout.

Comment: Would I do this using XML or Java code? Can you please provide a short walkthrough on how I should proceed.